# Complexity of computing 1- and 2- dimensional Brouwer fixed point

Tags: systems-of-equations, computational-complexity, fixed-point-theorems

Let $x\in[0,1]$，$f(x)\in[0,1]$ be a continuous function. Is there a polynomial-time method to find a (approximate) fixed point that $f(x)=x$?

If the answer to the above question is positve, how about the 2-dimensional case that $x\in [0,1]^2$ and $f(x)\in[0,1]^2$?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable,  one could hope to use Newton’s method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such polynomial time method, unfortunately. Finding a fixed point is known to be at least exponential, see "Exponential lower bounds for finding Brouwer fixed points" by Hirsch, et al. (link [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82810500.pdf))

It might also be worth checking out [Sperner's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_lemma), which gives a combinatorial proof of Brouwer's Theorem, and thus a constructive proof. Plus the paper linked above gives some good references for what algorithms people use in practice.

If all else fails, there is some good discussion on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105883/can-we-actually-find-any-fixed-points-with-brouwers-theorem), though they don't say much past what I've summarized here.

---

I hope this helps ^_^